# Using Postgres regexp_replace to erase all characters that are not in a provided list from a string

Tags: regex, string, postgresql, regex-negation

How would I erase all characters from a string that are not in a provided list of characters?

For instance: list of "valid" characters is `2,n,w,s`

String to be processed is `'24nQ/m'` and  result should be `'2n'`

Comment: Use a negated character class. Do not forget to pass the `g` flag to replace all occurrences.

Comment: I dont  see why this would be too broad a question. It is clearly worded and we saw two valid answers for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`regex_replace`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) to replace any other character with empty string:

```
SELECT *,
      regexp_replace(col, '[^2nws]','','g') AS replaced
FROM tab;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cb9f5/1/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════╗
║   col     ║ replaced ║
╠═══════════╬══════════╣
║ 24nQ/m    ║ 2n       ║
║ 2444nQ/m  ║ 2n       ║
║ aaa       ║          ║
║ Nn        ║ n        ║
╚═══════════╩══════════╝
```

If you want to ignore case use `'gi'` flag.

---

Another way is to use `translate` function:

```
SELECT *,
      translate(col, translate(col, '2nws','^'),'') AS replaced
FROM tab;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/03472/7/0)**</kbd>